# Heroku: Tomcat deployment issue

Tags: tomcat, heroku

I am deploying application to [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). I use tomcat 8 and Java 8 and locally it works fine. I generate `war` file using `jar -cvf projectname.war *` command. My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>trainer_for_vac</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <hibernate.version>5.0.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1207</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>8.0.24.0</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

I added `Procfile` as it's demanded by heroku specs:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

And heroku logs give me such exception:

```
2016-02-04T14:27:28.481053+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar webapp-runner.jar ${WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS:-"--expand-war"} --port 51689 ./target/trainer_for_vac-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`
2016-02-04T14:27:30.668475+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2016-02-04T14:27:30.662818+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2016-02-04T14:27:31.475129+00:00 app[web.1]: Expanding trainer_for_vac-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war into /app/target/tomcat.51689/webapps/expanded
2016-02-04T14:27:31.475228+00:00 app[web.1]: Adding Context  for /app/target/tomcat.51689/webapps/expanded
2016-02-04T14:27:32.271282+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 04, 2016 2:27:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
2016-02-04T14:27:32.274659+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 04, 2016 2:27:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
2016-02-04T14:27:32.261615+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2016-02-04T14:27:32.274662+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
2016-02-04T14:27:32.218347+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 04, 2016 2:27:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
2016-02-04T14:27:32.261610+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 04, 2016 2:27:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
2016-02-04T14:27:32.218351+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-51689"]
2016-02-04T14:27:32.271285+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting service Tomcat
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689684+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 04, 2016 2:27:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
2016-02-04T14:27:32.637943+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: No global web.xml found
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689689+00:00 app[web.1]: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
2016-02-04T14:27:32.637937+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 04, 2016 2:27:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689694+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689690+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689697+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689693+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689691+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689687+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: A child container failed during start
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689694+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689692+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689695+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689696+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689706+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1616)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689708+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689703+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689699+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689705+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:156)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689702+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/websocket/DeploymentException
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689711+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689700+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689704+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689698+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689709+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689713+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689712+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689714+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689702+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689716+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689715+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 18 more
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689709+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689707+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689707+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1128)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689701+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691438+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691436+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: A child container failed during start
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691437+00:00 app[web.1]: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689710+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691442+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691442+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691440+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691440+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689713+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691441+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.689704+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:186)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691449+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691451+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691453+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691455+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691443+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691444+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691445+00:00 app[web.1]:    at webapp.runner.launch.Main.main(Main.java:230)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691447+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691448+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.692231+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691445+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:337)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691448+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.692749+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691454+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691451+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.693245+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 2 more
2016-02-04T14:27:32.692859+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.692361+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.693174+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.693480+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691433+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 04, 2016 2:27:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
2016-02-04T14:27:32.693549+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691446+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691450+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.693651+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691453+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691439+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691456+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-04T14:27:32.692614+00:00 app[web.1]:    at webapp.runner.launch.Main.main(Main.java:230)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.693875+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
2016-02-04T14:27:32.693723+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 4 more
2016-02-04T14:27:32.694009+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.692467+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:337)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.694082+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.694254+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2016-02-04T14:27:32.693380+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
2016-02-04T14:27:32.691452+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
2016-02-04T14:27:32.692997+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
2016-02-04T14:27:32.694183+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-02-04T14:27:33.870195+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-02-04T14:27:32.841495+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-02-04T14:27:33.902287+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

The content of my *.war:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2.0 unx        0 b- stor 16-Feb-03 17:27 META-INF/
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      299 bl defN 16-Feb-03 17:27 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx      114 bl defN 16-Feb-03 17:27 META-INF/maven/groupId/trainer_for_vac/pom.properties
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx     3450 bl defN 16-Feb-02 18:25 META-INF/maven/groupId/trainer_for_vac/pom.xml
drwxrwxr-x  2.0 unx        0 b- stor 16-Feb-03 17:24 WEB-INF/
drwxrwxr-x  2.0 unx        0 b- stor 16-Feb-03 17:24 WEB-INF/classes/
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx      977 bl defN 16-Feb-02 17:55 WEB-INF/classes/User.hbm.xml
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx       75 bl defN 16-Feb-03 17:27 WEB-INF/classes/application.properties
drwxrwxr-x  2.0 unx        0 b- stor 16-Feb-03 17:24 WEB-INF/classes/controller/
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx     2882 bl defN 16-Feb-03 17:21 WEB-INF/classes/controller/Application.class
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx      920 bl defN 16-Feb-03 17:21 WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml
drwxrwxr-x  2.0 unx        0 b- stor 16-Feb-03 17:24 WEB-INF/classes/model/
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx      692 bl defN 16-Feb-03 17:21 WEB-INF/classes/model/User.class
drwxrwxr-x  2.0 unx        0 b- stor 16-Feb-03 17:24 WEB-INF/classes/util/
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx      545 bl defN 16-Feb-03 17:21 WEB-INF/classes/util/CommonUtil.class
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx     1427 bl defN 16-Feb-03 17:21 WEB-INF/classes/util/HibernateUtil.class
drwxrwxr-x  2.0 unx        0 b- stor 16-Feb-03 17:24 WEB-INF/lib/
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   445288 bl defN 15-Dec-18 14:49 WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx     4467 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx    62873 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/classmate-1.1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   588337 bl defN 15-Dec-25 16:01 WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   313898 bl defN 15-Dec-18 14:49 WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx    71283 bl defN 15-Dec-25 16:01 WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx  3111916 bl defN 15-Dec-25 16:01 WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-3.6.3.Final.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   100884 bl defN 15-Dec-25 16:01 WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   697321 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx    46989 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.6.4.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   258877 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.6.4.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx  1171262 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.6.4.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   644148 bl defN 15-Dec-25 16:01 WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx    66802 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx    16430 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx    15071 bl defN 15-Dec-25 16:01 WEB-INF/lib/jta-1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx     4595 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.13.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx    24137 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   280928 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   455041 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/logback-core-1.1.3.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   607093 bl defN 16-Feb-02 17:21 WEB-INF/lib/postgresql-9.4.1207.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx    33088 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   269579 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.16.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   370051 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   731512 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   540376 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   750598 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx     2219 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx     2254 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx     2218 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx     2241 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx     2226 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx  1097552 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx  1078737 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   262990 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   767333 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   874575 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx  2829987 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   238012 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.30.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx    40845 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.30.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx   245948 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar
-rw-rw-r--  2.0 unx    63777 bl defN 15-Dec-24 18:34 WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

Could anyone give me a prompt what is wrong here and what should I do to fix it. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is a missing class which is in a library which would seem to have different implementations depending on your Servlet container.

You are developing locally on Tomcat and bundle an embedded Tomcat with your application but appear to try to run the remote application in Jetty?

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

I would suggest that what you want to do is run it in the bundled Tomcat server:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```